# Getting a 403 error on Google Indexing API

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, service-accounts, google-indexing-api

I want to execute on "Google Indexing API" Code.

```
<?php
require_once 'google-api-php-client-2.2.2/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();


// service_account_file.json is the private key that you created for your service account.
$client->setAuthConfig('service_account_file.json');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/indexing');

// Get a Guzzle HTTP Client
$httpClient = $client->authorize();
$endpoint = 'https://indexing.googleapis.com/v3/urlNotifications:publish';

// Define contents here. The structure of the content is described in the next step.
$content = '{
  \"url\": \""http://example.com/jobs/42.html\",
  \"type\": \"URL_UPDATED"
}';

$response = $httpClient->post($endpoint, [ 'body' => $content ]);
$status_code = $response->getStatusCode();

echo $status_code;
?>
```

But in response, I get an error: 403.

I created on service account and Site Verification is complete

I want to add on service account email address in the Google Search Console.

what is the issue in our code?

Appreciate any help and ideas. Thanks!

Comment: 403 what?  Can you post the full error message?

Comment: I get an error - "403 - Forbidden"

Comment: Did you add the service account as a user?

Comment: yes, i have add on  service account email address in Google Webmaster.

Comment: Double check that you have to add the service account to the search console property, then give it permission and then make it an owner and you shouldn't get the permissions error again.

Comment: I set on permission is "Owner" -  https://www.screencast.com/t/8faEPbde